# When did Dr. Betruger turn evil?

Tags: video-games, doom

*(note: possible D3 spoilers ahead)*

Aptly named Dr. Malcolm Betruger is the main adversary in Doom 3 and Doom 3: RoE. In some audio log it is stated that he teleported to hell and was somehow *changed* when he returned. This implies that he made some sort of pact with some demons or was possessed by them. However, I was wondering whether he already planned to do so before entering the portal (maybe even before starting to work at UAC) or if he went into the teleporter for some legit (research?) reason and then was corrupted after reaching hell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think he planned something beforehand. The technology was developed right under his supervision, so I don't think he could forsee that they will be able to access hell.

Why he decided to go to the teleporter, no one knows, and Betruger obviously can't answer for himself, so there's the area for speculation. Probably he was just an eggheaded scientist who wanted to see what's on the other side himself. He was just so obsessed with the newly discovered dimension, nothing would stop him from exploring it. But I'm sure that getting possessed and eventually turning into Maledict wasn't his intention.

Comment: Is this a guess, or do you have any references?

Comment: @bitmask The first paragraph is supported by the [information by Ian McCormick that they were creating new science](http://members.iinet.net.au/~tmorrow/doom3/video_disks.html) (Teleportation Experiments disk). They couldn't have known what to expect. The second paragraph, as I said, is my own speculation based on the known facts. If Betruger had been committed to releasing hell before going to the portal, there wouldn't have been any need to additionally brainwash him, but it is made clear by the other scientists that they did something to his mind during his trip.

Comment: Well, they gave him supernatural powers, so that had to change him. Also he could have disguised him before entering the portal to appear "normal".

Comment: @bitmask Which powers did he get? He turned to Maledict much later, at the base he didn't exhibit any unnatural powers and appeared as human as before, only not right in the mind. The thought about disguise I didn't quite get, could you explain a bit? He coudn't have anything to do with the demons from the start since the technology was new, and Betruger had no direct contacts with them before he went through the portal. So we have to assume he was a normal human at least before this event. And probably even was still human before the final transformation into Maledict.

Comment: He could transform marines to his Commando-Zombies by some kind of magic. Also he is constantly speaking to you even though he's not physically present (it doesn't sound like the voice that is heard through speakers -- also you can hear his mad laughter while you're outside (sort of), when he destroys the skybridge). Although the technology was new, he could have found (e.g.) old scriptures before building the teleporter. If that were true, and he was working towards opening the Hellgate, he could have acted "normal" before he succeeded to fool his colleagues and employers.

Comment: @bitmask The tablets were discovered a long time ago, at the site 3 along with the soul cube, and the soul cube was found in 2104. The game is a little inconsitent here, though, it is said that the first chamber was found in 2115, but that's still a long time ago. Betruger started to focus on teleportation only for the last year which is 2145. So the tablets have already been studied thoroughly, Betruger had access to the same information as everyone else. Transforming soldiers is a good point, forgot about it. Then he could go to the teleporter with bad intentions (but not necessarily).